# how to grep one string occuring multiple times from same file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, solaris

I want to capture a string `1 row affected..`. But problem is there are no of such string present in the same file.

My concern to capture `1 row affected..` only which is present after the string `UPDATE kplustp..Service SET Service_Name = "PositionService", ServiceType = \'Z\', Hostname = " "` in log file. `1 row affected..` will be present after 3 4 sentences from  `Job completed successfully`.

I am working on solaris.

How to do?

Comment: Can you post an exact sample input? Is there any char in between "job completed successfully" and "1 row affected"?

Comment: Are these on the same line? different lines?

Comment: @user3164140 Don't re-post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21259447/1523648)! Instead, edit your question if you need to change something.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { if (/job completed successfully/) { $flag=1; } elsif (/1 row affected/) { print; } else { $flag=0; } }'
```

Comment: Is it perl script? I dont have any knowledge about perl script.Kindly elaborete by which extention should i save it? how to run it?

Comment: You can copy/paste my answer directly to the shell command line, and put your input file after it. Or, save everything between the `'` to a file `mygrep.pl`, then run `perl mygrep.pl inputfile`

Comment: This Perl snippet could be shortened using the `-n` flag and the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators): `perl -ne 'print if (/job completed successfully/ .. /1 row affected/)'`

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU grep, you can make use of its ability to display trailing context of matches:

```
cmd... | grep -A 5 "Job completed successfully" | grep "1 row affected"
```

The first `grep` will look for the string `Job completed successfully`, while also providing the five subsequent lines. It is in those lines that the other `grep` looks for `1 row affected`, and prints the match.

Comment: Good idea, however, he tagged solaris as well, so i wouldn't want to rely on GNU grep.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Good point, I've now made it clear that this depends on the ability to use GNU grep, which might not be a given.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some input like

```
$ printf "1 row affected...\nsomeline\nsomeline\nJob completed successfully\nsomeline\nsomeline\n2 row affected...\n3 row affected...\n"
1 row affected...
someline
someline
Job completed successfully
someline
someline
2 row affected...
3 row affected...
```

Let's say you only want the first row after "Job completed successfully" that contains "row affected". You can pipe it like so

```
| sed -n -e '/Job completed successfully/,$p' | grep -m 1 "affected"
```

e.g

```
$ printf "1 row affected...\nsomeline\nsomeline\nJob completed successfully\nsomeline\nsomeline\n2 row affected...\n3 row affected...\n" | sed -n -e '/Job completed successfully/,$p' | grep -m 1 "row affected"
2 row affected...
```

Where the `sed` matches any line containing `Job completed successfully` and returns from that line to the end of the file and `grep -m NUM` shows only the first `NUM` matches of grep. Could probably do it with one `sed` thought that gets more messy. If `grep -m NUM` is unavailable, you can just pipe to `head`, e.g.

```
| sed -n -e '/Job completed successfully/,$p' | grep "affected" | head -n 1
```

Comment: @user3164140 Where are you getting input? e.g. `sed -n -e '/Job completed successfully/,$p' logfile | grep "affected" | head -n 1` where `logfile` is whatever file if you're using a file. If you're using a variable you can echo and pipe it or pass it in `<<<`